# Python padding strings of different length

Tags: python, string, formatting, padding

So I have a problem I know can be solved with string formatting but I really don't know where to start.
What I want to do is create a list that is padded so that there is n number of characters before a comma as in the list below.

```
 1148,
   39,
  365,
    6,
56524,
```

Cheers and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight-forward way is to use the [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust) function. For example:

```
your_list = [1148, 39, 365, 6, 56524]

for element in your_list:
    print(str(element).rjust(5))
```

And you get:

```
 1148
   39
  365
    6
56524
```

There are also [`str.center()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.center) and [`str.ljust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) for string justification in other directions.

But you can also do it via formatting:

```
your_list = [1148, 39, 365, 6, 56524]

for element in your_list:
    print("{:>5}".format(element))
```

Comment: Sorry I screwed up, what I also should have said is that I'm writing rows to a csv file row by row not from a list. So what I need is for the first coma in each row to line up despite the first integer being different lengths.

Comment: You can use the above technique to 'pad' the first element of each of your rows - you just need to find out the maximum length (largest value) upfront. So loop through your data first and find the largest value, then get its character length (`len(str(largest_value))`) and then use that number for `str.rjust()` when padding the first element. Don't worry about comas and such - use the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to do your bidding when it comes to generating the actual CSV structure.

Answer (score 2):

See [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec).

You are looking for something like `"{:5d},".format(i)` where `i` is the integer to be printed with a width of 5.

For a variable `width`: `"{:{}d},".format(i, width)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know what n is you can do:
`'{:>n}'.format(number)`

So if you have a list of integers and wanted to format it as above you could do:

```
numbers = [1148, 39, 365, 6, 56524]
result = '\n'.join(('{:>5},'.format(x) for x in numbers))
```